# Get document title in Javascript (getElementsByTagName) returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I´m trying to get the current html title of a page in Javascript. I'm using the `getElementsByTagName("title")` function but it just returns me `undefined`.

I´m looking to output the title and substring 23 chars.

I hope someone can help me.

**code:**

```
function printName(){
  document.onLoad()
  var strng = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
  var resfin = strng.substring(0, strng.length - 23);
  document.write(resfin)
}
```

UPDATE: I tried this:

```
<button onclick="printName(-23)">Try it</button>
<br>
<script>
function printName(sub) {
  var str = document.title.substring(0, document.title.length + sub); 
  document.write(str)
}
printName(-23);

</script>
```

and now its printing out nothing.

Comment: What is `document.onLoad()` doing there?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]` returns the element, not the text. You should than access the text using `.textContent` - or just simply use `document.title`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd simply use `document.title`

```
function pageTitle(sub){
  return document.title.substring(0, document.title.length + sub)
}

console.log( pageTitle(-23) )
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title

Comment: I used this: 
function printName(sub) {
  var str = document.title.substring(0, document.title.length + sub); 
  document.write(str)
}
printName(-23); 

And it print out nothing

Answer (score -1):

You can use 
`document.title` 
I would advise you to review this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title

Comment: Does this answer improves on the other already posted here?

Comment: When I type there were no answers for her time!